# Every Python-related executable broken: "Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module"

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm very new to python and especially to its ecosystem. Today, I was trying to invoke a python command from my command line that worked perfectly yesterday, but today I got the following fatal error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site'

Current thread 0x00000cac (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

While trying to find the problem, I soon realized that it was not special to my command. In fact, all python-related executables produce the same error when invoked from any command prompt, no matter where I am in my filesystem. `python`, `python3`, `anaconda` (and its prompt), `conda`, `pip`, `pip3`, ... All of these suddenly don't work anymore. They all fail with the same error message, only the thread is altering.

In my research I found a very similar error very often, but it was about the `encodings` module. Also I haven't read about issues where the entire python ecosystem just broke.

Solutions to said similar error seem to include doing something with the `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` envs **if they exist**. But I don't have them, neither as user variable nor as system var.

I installed python by installing anaconda3 via scoop. It should be the latest version (2020.11). I've been using the installation inside of `PyCharm` as well as via the command line.

Does anyone know what the problem here could be? I'm kinda stuck here because I can't even use conda or pip for diagnostics, like calling `conda list` to find out more about the `site` packages' status. So, if anyone could help me with this, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: There's no harm in creating those environment variables. Most installations won't create them automatically for you, so when setting up a new Python environment, it's exceedingly common --- even I'd say standard --- to create those environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! From what I've read, people say that these environment variables (sometimes created by anaconda) are the reason why this error occurs when working in a virtual environment. That is why I haven't set them up so far. But I can try it out. Where do they have to point to?

Comment: Do you have a file, folder or module named `site` (or `site.py`)?

Comment: @MattThompson I was just trying out some stuff with manim (https://github.com/3b1b/manim). The only file I created for this was `scene.py`. It lies in a folder called `first-proj` which itself lies in `manim-projects`. This is all. So, I guess, no file, folder or module called `site`..

Comment: Good, I just wanted to rule that out. Unfortunately, I can't offer any suggestions other than completely re-installing Anaconda.

Comment: @MattThompson This actually worked, but I have no idea why. I kinda don't want to post this as an answer because this isn't really a fix.. Also, I don't know if this will happen again.

Comment: Good to hear - not the first time that reinstalling Anaconda fixed a cryptic error, and it won't be the last

Comment: @MattThompson man, I'm already starting to love python... Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 2):

I had this error.

For me, I had some project tree (fictitious):

```
doc/
├── project/
│   ├── embedded/
|   |   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── deep_file
│   │   └── utils/
│   │       └── os.py # < This one! Look here!!
│   │       └── deep/
│   │           └── folder/
│   │               └── very_deep_file
│   └── less_deep_file
|...
```

Within this tree, I had a file named `.../utils/os.py`.

Pycharm debug mode would find this `os.py` and use it in place of [the default `os.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). To solve this problem, I renamed `os.py` to something else.

What a dummy I am! Hopefully this saves other people time and headache!!

Comment: I just encountered a variant of this--in my case it was a file in my project called `types.py`, but the upshot is the same. I resolved the problem by renaming the file to one that does not conflict with builtin python files.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I had a file called types.py, and just assumed that that won't break anything (because why on earth should it?!?!?!?), and that broke everything.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I had a python file called stat.py in the working directory.
After deleting it, everything returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I cannot use any command in the anaconda Scripts folder.  The anaconda new install was using Python 3.8 while I had system variable PYTHONPATH set up for the paths for Python 3.9.  My solution was to delete the PYTHONPATH system variable, and the anaconda navigator worked again.

Comment: "Solutions to said similar error seem to include doing something with the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME envs if they exist. But I don't have them, neither as user variable nor as system var."

Answer (score -1):

The thing happened to me too. It fixed automatically when I first ran it without importing the modules and then added modules and ran again. For me it was the time module

Comment: its not technically an answer, rather it should be posted as a comment, i know you cannot do that right now, but wait to get there.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
executing python from command prompt failed with very same error (which was working fine earlier).
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\.......\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 879, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1012, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 672, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

However after restarting my windows machine, i didn't get this error.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).